# Powershell Script to Quick-Switch Python 3.4 and 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, powershell, python-3.x

I've been using Python 3.4 for my personal projects, but was recently brought on a Python 2.7  project at work. I wrote a Powershell script to switch between versions on my home computer.

My current version: https://github.com/ElizabethAB/PythonVersionSwitch/blob/master/PythonSwitch.ps1

This works, but after restarting my computer. Is there a way to make this work without having to restart?

Comment: Since 3.3, Python brings a [launcher](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/) in windows (py.exe) which decides the version of Python to use. Just add a unix shebang like `#!/usr/bin/python2` at the top of your file and it will run the correct version.

Comment: user3557327, my concern is also for functionalities like pip and detection of installed Python versions by certain installation packages (hello, numpy). It's not a strict necessity, obviously, it would just be a convenience tool if I could double-click a .ps1 on my desktop and go from personal projects-mode to work-mode and back.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Powershell. However I have found if I go to the main dir for the version I wish to use: (`C:\python27` or `C:\python34`) and run the `.exe` (type: `python.exe`)  Powershell with start that version.

All I have to do now is `exit()` python and now that's the default version I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to switch the system Python, just use the shebang line `#!/usr/bin/python2` or `#!/usr/bin/python3` at the start of each file.

If you are concerned about `pip` and installing the correct libraries ensure that you always use `virtualenv` for your Python projects. Create a `requirements.txt` fil for the project and use `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install the libraries. Avoid installing any third-party libraries into the system Python.

You can find a Powershell wrapper for virtualenv here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper-powershell/2.7.1